# Calculate results between columns according different parameters in sql, r or python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, r

Hi All I have this problem, I'm looking to calculate the days between Dates, with the following premises:

- Status A is the base date, all the calculations have to take this date as a reference (group by ID)
- I must take the older date for status B, C, D
- I must calcule the days and showing in different columns

Ex.

**generate the table with R**

```
ColID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)        
ColStatus = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "C")
ColDate = c("01/01/2018","02/03/2018", "05/04/2018", "04/05/2018", "04/05/2018", "02/01/2018", "04/03/2018", "05/04/2018")
data.frame(ColID, ColStatus, ColDate)
```

How I proceed with the calculation

```
For ColID = 1

Status A = 01/01/2018
Status B (I Have to select the older one) = 02/03/2018
Status C = 04/05/2018
Status D = 04/05/2018

ResultColB = 02/03/2018 - 01/01/2018 = 60
ResultColC = 04/05/2018 - 01/01/2018 = 123
ResultColD = 04/05/2018 - 01/01/2018 = 123
```

Result table (in days)

**generate the table with R**

```
ColID = c(1,2)
ResultColStatusB = c(60,0)
ResultColStatusC = c(123,61)
data.frame(ColID, ResultColStatusB, ResultColStatusC, ResultColStatusB)
```

The problem can be solved in R, Python or SQL, what recommend me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution in R:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ColID, ColStatus) %>% 
  summarise(min_date = min(parse_date_time(ColDate, "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(ColID) %>%
  summarise(a_b = as.period(interval(min_date[ColStatus=="A"], 
                                     min_date[ColStatus=="B"])) %/% days(1) - 1,
            a_c = as.period(interval(min_date[ColStatus=="A"], 
                                     min_date[ColStatus=="C"])) %/% days(1) - 1,
            a_d = as.period(interval(min_date[ColStatus=="A"], 
                                     min_date[ColStatus=="D"])) %/% days(1) - 1) %>%
mutate_all(funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Output:

```
  ColID   a_b   a_c   a_d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.   60.  123.  123.
2    2.    0.   61.    0.
```

Explanation:

1. Convert `ColDate` to date type, and get the earliest date for each `ColStatus`
2. Compute the time interval, in days, between `A` and each other `ColStatus` value.
3. Convert `NA` values to `0`.

---

Another method in R using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
#convert string Dates to integer
df[, ColDate := as.numeric(as.Date(ColDate, format="%d/%m/%Y"))]
cols <- c("B","C","D")
#pivot table without A into a wide table
dcast(df[ColStatus!="A"], ColID ~ ColStatus, min, fill=NA_integer_, value.var="ColDate")[ 
    #join with table containing only A and do the differencing
    df[ColStatus=="A"], on=.(ColID),
    (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - i.ColDate), .SDcols=cols]
```

---

Or using `base` R:

```
df$ColDate <- as.integer(as.Date(df$ColDate, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
cols <- c("B","C","D")
by(df, df$ColID, function(x) {
    aDate <- x$ColDate[x$ColStatus=="A"]
    vapply(cols, 
        function(id) if(any(x$ColStatus==id)) min(x$ColDate[x$ColStatus==id]) - aDate 
            else NA_integer_, 
        integer(1))
})
```

---

Data:

```
ColID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)        
ColStatus = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "C")
ColDate = c("01/01/2018","02/03/2018", "05/04/2018", "04/05/2018", "04/05/2018", "02/01/2018", "04/03/2018", "05/04/2018")
df <- data.frame(ColID, ColStatus, ColDate)
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12!

Comment: Thank you! I just have one issue when I executed the first solution (tidyverse) I recieved this comment Note: method with signature ‘Timespan#Timespan’ chosen for function ‘%/%’,
 target signature ‘Period#Period’.
 "Period#ANY", "ANY#Period" would also be valid
estimate only: convert to intervals for accuracy
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: assignment of an object of class <U+0093>logical<U+0094> is not valid for slot <U+0091>.Data<U+0092> in an object of class <U+0093>Period<U+0094>; is(value, "numeric") is not TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import pandas as pd 
Dic = {'ColID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       'ColStatus': ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "C"], 
       'ColDate': ["01/01/2018", "02/03/2018", "05/04/2018", "04/05/2018",
        "04/05/2018", "02/01/2018", "04/03/2018", "05/04/2018"]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(Dic) 
df.ColDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ColDate, format='%d/%m/%Y') 
conditions = [df.ColID==n for n in df.ColID.unique()] 
choices = [df[(df.ColID==n) & (df.ColStatus=='A')]['ColDate'].min() for n in df.ColID.unique()] 
df['Amin'] = pd.np.select(conditions, choices) 
df['days'] = df.ColDate - df.Amin 
df = df[df['days'].dt.days>0]
```

[image]

Comment: OP notes: `02/03/2018 - 01/01/2018 = 60`...looks like `D/M/Y`